# An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I am working on Symfony 3.4 project, and have been facing a weird issue. The web debug toolbar fails to load and instead gives an error "An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar. Open the web profiler."  Here is the screenshot
[image]

And when I click on Open the web profiler link it takes me to another exception page. Here is its screenshot

[image]

So after hours of debugging I was able to figure out that the issue is inside a 
 custom listener. It is registered in my services.yml as follows:

```
services:
    language.kernel_request_listener:
        class: TraceBundle\Listeners\LanguageListener
        arguments:
            - "@service_container"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: setLocale }
```

And here is the LanguageListener.php:

```
<?php

namespace TraceBundle\Listeners;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;


class LanguageListener{

    private $token_storage;

    private $securityContext;

    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $containerInterface)
    {
        $this->container = $containerInterface;
        $this->securityContext = $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker');
        $this->token_storage = $this->container->get('security.token_storage');
    }

    public function setLocale(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {


        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }

            if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
            $user = $this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser();
            $userLocale = $user->getTenant()->getLanguage()->getValue();
            $tenantid = $this->container->get('tenant_manager')->getTenantId($user);
            $request = $event->getRequest();
            $request->attributes->set('tenantid', $tenantid);
            if ($userLocale) {
                $request->setLocale($userLocale);
                $translator = $this->container->get('translator');
                $translator->setLocale($userLocale);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I comment the following lines:

```
if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
            $user = $this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser();
            $userLocale = $user->getTenant()->getLanguage()->getValue();
            $tenantid = $this->container->get('tenant_manager')->getTenantId($user);
            $request = $event->getRequest();
            $request->attributes->set('tenantid', $tenantid);
            if ($userLocale) {
                $request->setLocale($userLocale);
                $translator = $this->container->get('translator');
                $translator->setLocale($userLocale);
            }
```

the error goes away and the profiler loads as expected.

I've tried `var_dump()` after every line and all the values seem to be fine. the service tenant_manager works fine as well as the translator service. What am I missing here? Let me know if you need more code.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** As requested here is my security.yml:

```
security:

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username  

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                success_handler: authentication.handler.login_success_handler 
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

#            logout:       true
            logout: 
                path:   /logout
                target: /login

            anonymous:    true        

        js_router:
            pattern: ^/(js\/routing)
            security: false

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/dashboard, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/campaigns, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/dashboard, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/lives, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/colleagues, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/addcolleague, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/adminpage, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/test, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: please provide your `security.yml` code

Comment: It might be a priority issue if your listener is processed too soon.  You could try setting priority: -256 in your service definition.  But probably not.  Consider ignoring route _wdt and see if that helps.

Comment: @Cerad when I debug kernek.request listeners I can see the priority is 0 for LanguageListener::setLocale() method

Comment: @Pavel I've updated the question with security.yml

Comment: Did not really think that priority was the problem.  The other thing you might try is getting in the security context and token storage services from inside of your listener method instead of in the constructor.  But because your problem only seems to occur with the debug _wdt route then simply ignoring it should work.

Comment: @Cerad Tried getting in the security context and token storage services from inside listener method instead of in the constructor. No luck! How do I ignore the debug_wdt route?

Comment: if ($request->attributes->get('_route') === '_wdt') return;

Comment: @Cerad ignoring the route works. But I have another route that causes issue as well. Is it a good practice to ignore routes like this?

Comment: Nope.  Ignoring routes is a bad thing and just pushes the problems away.  The debug route is kind of a special case but you have something else going on.  Consider starting a fresh 3.4 project and then copy/paste your code a bit at a time until the problem reveals itself.  Could be anywhere.

Comment: ok. Thanks a lot Cerad :)

Comment: As i saw you have a problem with the javascript router. You can try to regenerates routes ([doc](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/commands.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some experiments with your code and found this:

Removing these lines solves the problem:

```
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
```

also replacing them with these helps:

```
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        anonymous: true
```

So I can conclude that `security: false` leads to setting security token to `null` behind the scenes.

So far I didn't locate this mechanism (will keep trying), so would be grateful for any help.

Another solution is to check if token is not null right inside of your listener:

```
    if (null !== $this->token_storage->getToken()
        && $this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
        ...
    }
```

But it makes your code to care about situation caused by your dev config (dev firewall) so I decide it's not the best way.

Any comments/additions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem using a custom Listener with TokenStorageInterface.

Here's a scaled down version of my listener code:

```
class DatabaseUserAuthenticationListener {
    private $authToken;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage) {
        if ($tokenStorage->getToken())  {
            $this->authToken = $tokenStorage->getToken();
        }
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)  {
        if ($this->authToken)  {
            $this->authToken->setAttribute("blah", true);
        }
    }
}
```

In my case the offending line was `$this->authToken->setAttribute("blah", true);`.  `$this->authToken` ends up being `null` when `_wdt` routes are called (since they have no user context).  At least that's my theory.

@Pavel is correct in that Symfony is setting the token to null between requests, although I don't think it's `security: false` that's doing it.

Checking that your token exists and is not null or empty before working with it (`if ($this->authToken) {...}`) fixes the issue (at least for me).

@utkarsh2k2, I'm sure you already fixed your issue... if not, you could try checking that `$this->token_storage->getToken()` has something in it before calling `->getUser()`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was, when I star a proyect almost clean still have that problem:
"An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar. Open the web profiler."

My Solution: 
I added a .htaccess to the public directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

With that only the toolbar appear.